# NDVI Python image showing inverse

Tags: python, raster, ndvi, matplotlib

I am trying to calculate NDVI using python and landsat imagery. I am able to calculate ndvi using the following equation:

```
def ndvi(sat, fp):
    raster = rasterio.open(fp)
    if sat.lower() == 'l8':
       red = raster.read(4)
       nir = raster.read(5)
    if sat.lower() == 'l5':
       red = raster.read(3)
       nir = raster.read(4)
    red = red.astype('float64')
    nir = nir.astype('float64')
    ndvi = (nir - red) /(nir + red)
    display(ndvi, 'Greens')
def display(img, ramp):
    plt.figure(figsize=(200, 200), dpi=80, facecolor='w', edgecolor='k')
    plt.imshow(img, cmap=ramp)
    plt.colorbar()
    plt.xticks([])
    plt.yticks([])
    plt.show()
```

This produce an image that looks like:
[image]
The image appears to show the inverse of what should be shown. The areas in the rectangles are golf courses that are shown with negative ndvi and the highways which are circled are displayed with a high ndvi. I know I could multiple everything by -1 and get the correct image but I would like to know why this happens.
Here is the corresponding image processed in GEE for reference:
[image]

Comment: Works as expected for me with a random Landsat 8 image. However, I get similar to your results if I accidentally on purpose use Landsat 8 B3 & B4 as the R & NIR bands. Perhaps somewhere in your logic you've specified the satellite ("`sat.lower()`" as "l5" instead of "l8". ? Can you edit your question with more details about your script.

Comment: @Luke I updated the code above with the full functions. The script takes a file path to a tiff and you specify whether your using landsat five or landsat 8 and it display the image using matplotlib

Comment: Can you also provide more info about how you specify in your code what the satellite is? And some details about the data (i.e, where you got it from, processing level, filename, datatype etc. perhaps you could provide the output of a `rio info` or `gdalinfo` report on your raster).